# Command list for modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Is there a way to see a command list for each module? For example, `help` in a command prompt lists a lot of commands, and then you can write `command /help` to get further knowledge.

Does Python have anything similar?

Comment: You can use `dir(module)` to see the names defined in the module, and `help(name)` to access their docstrings.

Comment: There is also `module.__dict__`